# Getting original height after a crop filter, chaining filters

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having a bit of trouble with my FFMPEG command, what I require is to grab the 2 pixels at the 20% from the bottom, then scale that up to fill out everything from that to the bottom.

I'm using *ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1*

I was originally doing this by exporting twice (once to create the overlay and then to put it on top of the original) but that has become to inefficient.

But have got it down to work in one export

My current command is:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex "\
[0:v]crop=iw:2:0:ih*0.8[cropped];\
[cropped]scale=iw:538,setsar=1:1[bot];\
[0:v][bot]overlay=0:H-(H*0.2)" \
"output.mp4"
```

as you can see in the crop filter I do get the 2 pixels and then pipe that into the scale filter, then at the end apply the cropped and scaled part on top of the original video.

I can set the **iw** as that has not changed from the original width, but the **538** is what bothers me with this.

This is where I am not able to use **ih*0.2** because the value of **ih** is being taken from the crop filter which is 2px.

I have tried using multiple inputs to the scale filter to get [0:v]'s height, but scale does not accept multiple inputs.

I got suggested **set=** and **expr=** for making variables inside ffmpeg, but they all return with errors ( no such filter: 'set' & option 'expr' not found)

So is there a way to get and use the size of the input file inside of the scale filter(in my case) or in the middle of a filter chain?

Comment: I don't think you need to bother with `set`/`expr` (not sure what these are) or anything like that. Add your system as a tag and e.g. `ffprobe` + bash/PowerShell solution is quite easy to achieve, if yyou want it to be dynamic.

Comment: try this: `...[0:v]crop=iw:2:0:ih*0.8,scale=iw:iw/16*9*0.2[bot];...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the original input we can use the **scale2ref** filter to reference the size of the video input, instead of **scale** which only can reference the input from the filter before.

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex "\
[0:v]crop=iw:2:0:ih*0.8[cropped];\
[cropped][0:v]scale2ref=h=ih*0.2[bot][ref];\
[ref][bot]overlay=0:H-(H*0.2)" \
"output.mp4"
```

We start by cropping like the original code, then using a **scale2ref** filter with the **[cropped]** as the part we just cropped. Using **[0:v]** as the original file input to reference. Then to get the size of the **[0:v]** we can use **ih** and **iw** and if we wanted to use the size of **[cropped]** then we could use **main_h** and **main_w**.

Then we define the outputs at the end of **scale2ref** where **[bot]** is the part we just scaled from **[cropped]** and **[ref]** being the original input **[0:v]**(in our case remaining untouched), we must use the newly created output from **scale2ref** otherwise it will error out with an unconnected output.

Then overlaying the scaled on top of the original with the **overlay** filter.

[FFMPEG documentation about scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref)